# strcat and differences in return errors

Tags: c

I can use the following code to concatenate a string:

```
char str1[50] = "hello";
printf("%s\n", strcat(str1, " goodbye"));
```

Now, if I try and do something like this:

```
printf("%s\n", strcat( "start", " CONCAT-WORD"));
```

I get an error: `Abort trap: 6`. Two questions related to this. Sometimes when I get a pointer-misassignment error it shows up as `Bus Error: 11` and sometimes it shows up as `Abort trap: 6` or `Segmentation Error`. Why does one show up sometimes and others at other times? These are the only three C errors I've come across -- are these the most common, or are there other very common ones as well?

Secondly, why does `strcat` not allow you to write directly to a string? In the assignment it gives `char *strcat(char *str1, const char *str2)`, so I would think I could print the string directly, but I'm of course incorrect in thinking so. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a `Bus Error` when you're trying to access memory that has no address on the memory for example if you have an address in memory of type `1,3,5` and your program is trying to read on a 16 bits `0,2,4,6` in this case you will get a `Bus Error`. The segmentation fault appear when you try to read outside of the memory allocated.

For a `strcat`, you can't print it directly because you have to create enough space in memory to stock your value in it. So if you are trying to concatenate `toto` in `tata` without a malloc, it will try to write on the current value, so you will get a wonderful `segmentation fault`.

Comment: thanks for this explanation it's very helpful. Is there a way to do a "one-line" string concat then, or do you need to define an array before it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @Shared if they are just string literals, you can concatenate them by just leaving them next to each other: `printf("a simple" " concat");`. You only need to make space and use something like `strcat` if you have one or more string variables.